# Delimitate an area - google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I tried to find tools to delimitates a specific region area of a map
When the mouse is on a specific area, there is the region delimition which appears.

Like this website : 
http://www.police.act.gov.au/crime-and-safety/crime-statistics.aspx
or even livelovely maps

I try use google api Fusion Tables, but it seems it can't do what i want...
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling.html

Maybe do you have some advices ?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want? Is it mouse in/out events that you are looking for? It looks like the crime site is using Raphael (http://raphaeljs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

What I think you might want is doable using Fusion Tables. You just have to have the polygon data.

See http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2667/trunk/fusiontables/mouseover.html